# What are the aileron lengths of commercial and military aircraft?

Tags: ailerons

I would like to know the aileron lengths for different aircraft, such as:

1. Cessna [150](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cessna_150)
2. Airbus [A380](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airbus_A380), [A320](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airbus_A320_family)
3. Boeing [747](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_747), [777](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_777), [787](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_787_Dreamliner)
4. Lockheed Martin [F-22 Raptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_Martin_F-22_Raptor)

I have tried to search online, but was unsuccessful in finding the values. I also tried searching in some books but couldn't find the values there either.

Any help guiding me to the books or any resources which would give me the values would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to find these lengths yourself? Did you find any resources? From your question as it stands now, I can't tell if you have tried to find this yourself or if you are just asking the users here to find things for you. Please edit your question to add some more information.

Comment: this questions seems to ask a grocery list of data and I hardly see how this would be beneficial to anyone else except for the OP

Comment: Once I get home tonight, I'll go to my hangar (where I've all these aircraft parked) to measure the lengths. *Note to self: buy a measuring tape and a ladder on the way home.*

Comment: You can find technical drawings for the Airbus and Boeing aircraft, and from this you can measure the sizes yourself

Comment: would you also add why you need this info, and where you will use it. if you're trying to create a "look alike model", then pictures of the aircraft would be sufficient, if you're searching for some aerodynamic studies, then you should also need the area of the surfaces, etc..

Comment: I was actually trying to theoretically estimate the minimum lengths of the ailerons needed for some aircrafts by using the maximum roll rate at the maximum deflection of the aileron, moment of inertia of the plane, wing span etc. I wanted to know the actual length of the ailerons just to validate my calculations.

Comment: For larger airliners the question can not really be answered. All Boeing (and probably most other) that I am aware of use multiple combinations of ailerons and spoilers depending on flight mode. For example, after about 250-300kt the outermost ailerons are locked out and only the middle or inner surfaces are used. This is because at high speed the outer ailerons are too sensitive and can also cause the pivoting of the leading edge of the outer wing panel in the opposite direction causing control reversal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quite difficult to answer as some modern supersonic fighters  don't have just ailerons, but 'elevons', flaperons, tailerons and most of the time combine the movement of several control surfaces by computer to generate a desired effect.

Large civilian aircraft tend to have more than one pair. A relatively smaller set closer to the wing tips for slower speeds and a general large aileron closer to the wing root.

I would suggest you get a top-view of these aircraft. When you find our the length of the aircraft or wingspan you could derive it yourself through approximation.

Comment: Modern military aircraft have ailerons, but you'd be correct in your assumption that the majority of the roll control comes from the horizontal stabs.

Comment: For one...the F-16 does not have ailerons

Comment: The F18, F35, F15 and F22 all have ailerons.  The F-16 has flaperons, which combine both flaps and ailerons.